# Alexa sometimes not understanding city name

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

In my app, user has to tell the current city. My intent request is

```
{
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "cityName",
      "type": "AMAZON.US_CITY"
    }
  ],
  "intent": "cityIntent"
}
```

And my utterances are

```
cityIntent my city is {cityName} 
cityIntent my favorite city is {cityName} 
cityIntent {cityName} 
cityIntent change city to {cityName}
```

now when I am saying Alexa change city to Mumbai or My city is Miami, it is working fine but when alexa ask for the city name and I am replying with only city name like Mumbai Or Miami, it won't work. It calls for stopIntent

Comment: Let me know what have I posted wrong for getting -1?

Comment: Referring `but when alexa ask for the city name` Is this is a dialog kind of interaction ?

Comment: No, alexa is asking like.. ok tell me your city?

Comment: Do you see your cityIntent being called when alexa asks "ok tell me your city?" . You could try to print out the request json in the log.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon recently created a new slot type [***AMAZON.SearchQuery***](https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/a2716002-0f50-4587-b038-31ce631c0c07/enhance-speech-recognition-of-your-alexa-skills-with-phrase-slots-and-amazon-searchquery) which would perfectly suit your problem.